# how to use awk to get the location of current view in clearcase

Tags: unix, clearcase

I want to use awk to get the second directory pattern I am able to do the same using `cut -d` command and need to use reverse as there is a problem that space between the two dir does not remains the same.

Here is the string I just want the third pattern one marked in bold. I am able to achieve this with cut -d and rev but want to achieve it with awk.

```
* example_view    /nas/viewstore/admin/example_view.vws
```

please note the space between the two string varies so we cannot use a fixed value.

I used the following command to do so please take in to consideration of the * which comes when the view is set somewhere.

```
cleartool lsview -cview |rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev|xargs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` as shown below:

```
cleartool lsview -cview | awk '{print $NF}'
```

`$NF` refers to the last field and, by default, `awk` uses whitespace as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20951666/6309) (upvoted), to get the [view storage path](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_find_view_storage.htm) (for [dynamic view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_mvfs/glines_locate_storage_dirs.htm) or [snapshot view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_storage_dirs_ssv.htm)), I usually use string substitution when I am in a bash script:

```
cd /views/myStartedView
storagePath=$(cleartool lsview -cview)
storagePath="${storagePath#*/}/"
```

Comment: @yanivx I had to do this on *a lot of* views, and I found at the time `awk` much slower. YMMV. For one view, `awk` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think "cleartool pwv" (print working view) does the job.